# g:select disabled property doesn't work properly

Tags: grails, drop-down-menu, gsp, disabled-input

In my `.gsp` I have a dropdown select option.

```
<g:select id="id"
          name="name"
          disabled="${model.x == MyEnum.X}"   //<--- note here
          from="${MyEnum.values()}"
          optionValue="naturalName"
          noSelection="['': '']"
          value="${model?.x}"/>
```

The generated `.html` of this portion looks like this -

```
<select id="id" name="name" > //n <--- note here
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A" >A</option>
</select>
```

***note:** the `disabled` property is not generated!

**BUT** if I put the logic and value of *disabled* property inside a variable first -

```
<g:if test="${model.x == MyEnum.X}">
    <g:set var="disabled" value="true"/>
</g:if>
```

Then, use the variable inside `disabled` property -

```
<g:select id="id"
          name="name"
          disabled="${disabled}"     //<------here
          from="${MyEnum.values()}"
          optionValue="naturalName"
          noSelection="['': '']"
          value="${model?.x}"/>
```

**It works as expected!** I mean, generates `disabled="disabled"` at generated `.html` file -

```
<select id="id" name="name" disabled="disabled"> //n <--- here
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A" >A</option>
</select>
```

Can someone explain this *inconsistent* behavior why `.gsp` can not process **1'st** approach but the **2'nd**

I said *inconsistent* because on both approach I did the same `boolean` checking but `.gsp` works accurately on the second approach.

*FYI: my grails version is 2.4.4*

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like following which is working fine:

```
<div style="text-align: right;margin: 5px 10px;">
    State: <g:select name="state" from="${testapp.State.values()}" value="${testapp.State.HR}" disabled="${1==1}"/>
</div>
```

So, could you please share a sample application replicating the problem?

Comment: sue, I'll create a sample project on github and share the link.

Comment: well, creating a separate project made things clearer to myself! The problem was occurring because of `javascript` calling. No issues with `gsp` or `grails`. Thanks for showing interest on this question. Otherwise I'll be wondering in vein!

Comment: I am glad you found the problem. In my experience, most of the problem goes away while isolating them.